# Try Catch incorrect for value null in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am making a selection for api but when you do not have the contract informed you are returning an empty array [] but you should return contract not found.
I believe that the catch is in the wrong way, but I already did some other tests and it didn't work.

```
try {
     
      if(empty($contratos)){
        return response()->json(
          $contratos,
          200
        );
      }else{
        return response()->json([
          "message" => "Contract not found",
          "code" => "CONTRACT_NOT_FOUND"
        ], 406
        );
      }
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 406){
          return response()->json([
            "message" => "Contrato não encontrado",
            "code" => "CONTRACT_NOT_FOUND"
          ]);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there are no results from the query like this.

```
if ($contratos->isEmpty()) {
    return response()->json([
        "message" => "Contract not found",
        "code" => "CONTRACT_NOT_FOUND"
    ], 406);
} else {
    return response()->json($contratos, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should put a `dd($exceptopm->getStatusCode())`  in the exception block and see what is the status code returned, typically not found should be 404 instead of 406

you should also try to use a switch statement

```
switch($exception->getStatusCode()) {
    case 400:
        return [];
        break;
    case 404:
        return [];
        break;
    default:
        return [];
}
```